# setGroupingUsed(true) does not turn on grouping in DecinalFormat

Tags: java, decimalformat

For some reason the grouping doesn't work in my example. The output I get is: `4242424@52420` instead of `424 242@52420`(or similar)

```
double d = 4242424.5242;
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('@');
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
df = new DecimalFormat("######.00000", dfs);
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Comment: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00000", dfs);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) Javadoc:

> The grouping size is a constant number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for 100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000.

You are not setting an explicit grouping size, so it becomes 0 when you are constructing the `DecimalFormat` with the format you have (there is no grouping separator in your format).

```
double d = 4242424.5242;
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('@');
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("######.00000", dfs);
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
df.setGroupingSize(3); // set explicitely the grouping to 3
System.out.println(df.format(d)); // prints the expected 4 242 424@52420
```